# Reload content from JS api in bootstrap container when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a random quote generator and I want to make the container with the content reload when I click a button in another container. The commented area "what should go here" is where I think the action code should go. I'm not sure if I should go with something like $('quotecontainer').container(function(){}); and go from there, or if something else is needed entirely.

Here's the JS:

```
$('#newquotebutton').button();

$('#newquotebutton').click(function(){
    $(this).button('loading');
        // what should go here
    $(this).button('reset');
});
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="wherebuttonis" class="jumbotron-transparent">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 text-center">
                <button id="newquotebutton" class="btn btn-default" data-text-loading="loading...">New Quote</button></div></div></div></div>

<div id="quotetron" class="jumbotron-transparent">
        <div id = "quotecontainer" class="container text-center">
                <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.brainyquote.com/link/quotefu.js"></script>
                <small><i><a href="http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/topics/topic_funny.html" target="_blank">more Funny Quotes</a></i></small></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The remote script you provided seem to provide only one quote per day...
So you'll have to create your own local array of quotes to pick another quotes:

```
var quotes = ['quote one', 'quote two', 'quote three'];

$('#newquotebutton').button();

$('#newquotebutton').click(function(){
    var random_quote = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random()*quotes.length)];
    $(this).button('loading');        
    $('#newquotebutton').text(random_quote);
    $(this).button('reset');
});
```